# Why my CMake GUI looks different than usual

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I have reinstalled CMake many times and still I don't have the Configure and Generate options on the CMake GUI. Can someone tell me how I can delete the old configuration?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have hidden the CMake variables display (which includes the ***Configure*** and ***Generate*** buttons).

To fix this, hover your mouse pointer over the blank gray space directly under the "**Where to build the binaries**" textbox near the top, and the option to resize the window pane should display as your mouse pointer. You can click here and drag down vertically to re-expand the CMake variables display, which will show the buttons to ***Configure*** and ***Generate*** as well.