# cmake-gui missing GUI elements

Tags: windows, cmake, cmake-gui

When I run `cmake-gui.exe` most of the GUI elements are hidden: the only elements I can see are the **SourceDirectory** line, the **BinaryDirectory**  line and the Output panel. There are no cache values or search options displayed. There is however a comprehensive menu bar available.

I tried the old versions, the problem continues.

[image: Cmake GUI]

Comment: "There are no cache values" - CMake cache doesn't exist until the project is configured at least once.

Comment: It doesn't come after doing configure either. I am installing on another computer. The window I want comes first time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my CMake GUI looks different than usual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61411077/why-my-cmake-gui-looks-different-than-usual)