# Cannot view CMake Build Settings

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

My CMake is missing a view for me to make adjustments to CMake config. In other pictures online I see an additional window with flags that I can check. Mine only has one for the output.

[my cmake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rky3.png)
[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc7l8.png)

Comment: You need to press "Configure" for the first time. Only after that configuration options will appear.

Comment: @Tsyvarev After pressing "Configue" I just get the output. But I suppose to tick some flags. There should be a view with Name/Value headers, I'll add the picture of my output.

Comment: First you need to specify the Source and Build directories in those two boxes at the top. Then `configure` should show you some details.

Comment: @StAlphonzo Yes I have done that but configure did not give me more details. I''ll show it in a new picture.

Comment: Your cmake-gui looks like it's only showing the output pane. There is a middle pane that shows the variables along with a 'Search' textbox and some buttons, including the 'Configure' and 'Generate' buttons. I don't know Mac well at all but I see a little dark gray dot in the center top of the output window. Is it possible that is how you drag and resize panels? If so, pull that down some and it should reveal the missing middle pane. I confirmed on my version of cmake-gui (Linux), that i can drag and expand my output window so big that I can make the middle panel vanish.

Comment: @StAlphonzo I already tried that. In fact my current window size is small. As is when I open CMake. Is something wrong with my app. I installed different versions. All the same. Only the output window. Ill repost a new photo later showing my more of my screen outside of the application.

Comment: Duplicate question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61411077/why-my-cmake-gui-looks-different-than-usual

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for posting the duplicate as well. That didn't work? That should be the only issue considering you have the same symptoms. I don't have any other suggestions beyond that. You do have the correct App and nothing else should be required for install. If you use a command line, you could run ccmake ... it's a curses gui and is typically what I use when working with CMake.

Comment: @StAlphonzo no it worked. i posted it as answer but stack overflow said it was too short and converted it to a comment. im not sure how to mark as duplicate as i have seen others done.

Comment: @Gordon, I don't know how to mark it either but I will look since I can edit stuff. Either way, I'm glad your problem is resolved, that's the most important thing. Enjoy the rest of your work!

Comment: @StAlphonzo Thank you. I have found out how to 'mark' as duplicate. I clicked the flag button under my question and I clicked "as duplicate". But it requires some approval so we will have to wait. Thank you once again for your input on this question.